# Asyncstorage session not working react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have used `asyncstorage` for login and logout. But it is not working, when I open the app it always shows the login screen. Please have a look into my code,

//LoginFirst.tsx

```
let userID = response.data.details[0].id.toString();
                let userName = response.data.details[0].username.toString();
                let email = response.data.details[0].email.toString();
                let accountType = response.data.details[0].account_type.toString();
                let eventID = response.data.details[0].event_id;
                eventID = (eventID === null) ? 0 : eventID.toString();

                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userLoginStatus', 1);
                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userId', userID);
                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userName', userName);
                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userEmail', email);
                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userAccountType', accountType);
                SetUserStorage.setUserDetails('userEventID', eventID);

                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

//GetUserStorage.tsx

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const getUserDetails = async (sessionValue) => {
let userSession = '';

try {
    userSession = await AsyncStorage.getItem(sessionValue) || 0;
} catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
}

return userSession;
}
```

//SetUserStorage.tsx

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const setUserDetails = async (sessionType, sessionValue) => {
try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(sessionType, sessionValue);
} catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
}
}
```

//ClearUserStorage.tsx

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const clearAllStorage = async () => {
try {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();

    return 1;
} catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);

    return 0;
}
}
```

//Splash.tsx

```
export default class Splash extends Component {
async componentDidMount() {
let routeNames = 'LoginFirst';
const isLogin = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userLoginStatus');

setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: false });

  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

  if (isLogin !== null || isLogin === 'true') {
    routeNames = 'Home';
  } else {
    routeNames = 'LoginFirst';
  }

  // navigate(routeNames);

  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeNames })]
  });

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}, 2000);
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      style={styles.logo}
      source={require('../../../assets/logo.png')}
    />
  </View>
);
}
}
```

//Logout.tsx

```
logoutBtn = async () => {
    let clear = await clearStorage.clearAllStorage();

    if (clear) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginFirst');
    }
}
```

Each time when I open the app it shows the login screen. I have used a splash screen (Splash.tsx) to check the session.

How to persist the session and not show the login screen. Is there anything else to be done in my code.

Comment: what is the value of `isLogin` in your `setTimeout`?

Comment: @MikeM `isLogin` value is `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging in you are trying to store 1 in **userLoginStatus** but, We can only store strings in AsyncStorage.

So, every time when you get **userLoginStatus** from AsyncStorage, it returns null and that's why you always land on login screen.